MarkLogic - Performance Tuning - Improving Performance of MarkLogic XQuery for Large Dataset Search
I have an XQuery module that searches through various data sources and retrieves matching registered products based on IDs. However, I am experiencing performance issues when dealing with large datasets, especially when the number of IDs is large. Below is a description of the problem and the code involved.
Scenario:

Search all data like formulations, directions for use (dfu), etc.
Retrieve IDs (e.g., Id, prodId) from the results of the previous step.
Search for matching IDs in the RegisteredProduct (similar to a JOIN operation).
Return the registered products.
Return results in the search:search result format.

Problem Areas:
1. Performance Issue in Querying IDs: Here whatever IDs, PROD ids I got after searching almost entire database, I provided all IDs (millions of IDs) in the below code to match with registered product ids
let $regPrdQuery := if($allIds) then(cts:path-range-query("/envelope/instance/RegisteredProduct/id","=",$allIds)) else()

2. Performance Issue in Search Query Construction: In the below code I am passing millions of Registered product IDs as a part of an additional query (since I want to get the output like search:search). Please Refer to the complete code section for details.
let $new-extraction_options :=
    <search:options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
        { $extraction_options/*[local-name() != "additional-query"] }
        <search:additional-query>{$allProdsQuery}</search:additional-query>
    </search:options>

Constructing the search options with a potentially complex additional query is impacting performance.
Question:
How can I efficiently handle and optimize the search query construction to improve performance for large datasets?
Complete Code
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace ext = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/extsearch";

import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";
import module namespace cq = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/models/config-query" at "/MarkLogic/rest-api/models/config-query-model.xqy";
import module namespace json = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json" at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";

declare namespace roxy = "http://marklogic.com/roxy";
declare namespace rapi = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api";

declare
%roxy:params("q=xs:string", "format=xs:string?", "options=xs:string", "start=xs:string?", "pageLength=xs:string?")
%rapi:transaction-mode("update")
function ext:get(
    $context as map:map,
    $params as map:map
) as document-node()? {
    let $q := map:get($params, "q")
    let $format := (map:get($params, "format"),"json")[1]
    let $options := (map:get($params, "options"),"extraction")[1]
    let $extraction_options := ext:get-options($options)
    let $start :=  xs:int((map:get($params, "start"),"1")[1])
    let $pageLength := xs:int((map:get($params, "pageLength"),10)[1])
    let $searchParseQuery := if($q)then(cts:query(search:parse($q,$extraction_options)))else("")

    (: query to search all docs :)
    let $allDocsQuery :=
        cts:and-query((
            $searchParseQuery,
            ext:get-include-collections(),
            cts:not-query((ext:get-exclude-collections()))
        ))
    (: get the ids of all docs :)
    let $allIds :=
        cts:values((
            cts:path-reference("/envelope/instance/DirectionsForUse/prodId"),
            cts:path-reference("/envelope/instance/RegisteredProduct/id"),
            cts:path-reference("/envelope/instance/Formulation/id"),
            cts:path-reference("/envelope/instance/DirectionsForUse/id")
        ),(),(), $allDocsQuery)
    let $regPrdQuery := if($allIds) then(cts:path-range-query("/envelope/instance/RegisteredProduct/id","=",$allIds)) else()
    (: query to search all products :)
    let $allProdsQuery :=
        cts:and-query((
            $regPrdQuery,
            cts:query($extraction_options/search:additional-query/cts:and-query/*)
        ))
    let $new-extraction_options :=
        <search:options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
            { $extraction_options/*[local-name() != "additional-query"] }
            <search:additional-query>{$allProdsQuery}</search:additional-query>
        </search:options>
    let $results := search:search("", $new-extraction_options, $start, 10)
    let $params := map:map()
    let $response :=
        if(lower-case($format) eq "json") then(
            let $res :=
                if ($pageLength eq 0)
                then(xdmp:xslt-invoke("/lib/xslt/custom-search-transformer.xsl",$results,map:new((map:entry(xdmp:key-from-QName(fn:QName("", "populateResults")), fn:false())))))
                else(xdmp:xslt-invoke("/lib/xslt/custom-search-transformer.xsl",$results,map:new((map:entry(xdmp:key-from-QName(fn:QName("", "populateResults")), fn:true())))))
            return(xdmp:set-response-content-type("application/json"),xdmp:add-response-header("Content-type", "application/json"),$res)
        )
        else(
            let $res := if($pageLength eq 0) then($results/search:facet) else($results)
            return(xdmp:set-response-content-type("application/xml"),xdmp:add-response-header("Content-type", "application/xml"),$res)
        )
    return (document{$response},xdmp:set-response-code(200, "OK"))
};

declare function ext:get-options($name as xs:string) {
    xdmp:invoke-function(function() {
        let $options := fn:concat("/Default/product-FINAL/rest-api/options/",$name,".xml")
        return fn:doc($options)/*
    }, map:entry("database", xdmp:modules-database()))
};

declare function ext:get-include-collections() {
    cts:collection-query(("Extraction","Formulation","DirectionsForUse","latest","xyzzz","aaa","bbbb","cccc"))
};

declare function ext:get-exclude-collections() {
    cts:collection-query(("hidden","deleted"))
};

